# Regex of max 5 decimal separate by +

Tags: html, regex

i'm trying to make a regex to add to a input pattern (HTML) to check if is valid,
it need to be valid only if the input contain a string composed by decimal(with 1 or 2 number after comma) or integer number separated by a +
and maximum of 5 number
and it can not start or end with a + or it can not be possible to have a number with comma without number after (i use comma instead of dot for decimal)

for example

- `10+5,1+6,20` OK
- `10` OK
- `6+4+8,9+3+9+3` NO
- `10,2+4+6+` NO
- `10,+5` NO

i've tried with something like this but id doesn't work very well

```
((\d{1,3}|(\d*,\d{1,2})*)+(\+)?){1,5}
```

also i've tried with this:

```
^((\s*)|([0-9]\d{0,9}(\,\d{1,2})?%?))*(\+((\s*)|([0-9]\d{0,9}(\,\d{1,2})?%?))+){0,4}$
```

but it doesn't work very well with the 2 digit max for the decimal and ending +

any suggestions ??

i've made some test here:
https://regexr.com/5jsfv

it should pass the first 3 and faile on the last 4

thanks

Comment: `^\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}$`

Comment: Try: `"\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}$
```

In the HTML pattern attribute use it as

```html
pattern="\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0l8DeZ/1).

**NOTE**: If you want to limit the number of digits in the integer part to be max 3, replace the `\d+` with `\d{1,3}`:

```js
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `pattern` regex)
- `\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `,` and one or two digits
- `(?:\+\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}` - zero to four occurrences of a `+` char followed with one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `,` and one or two digits
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `pattern` regex)

Comment: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?(?:\+\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,2})?){0,4}$` i've changed the \d+ at the beginning and in the middle to a \d{1,3} to limit to max 3 digit number

Comment: @Darkmagister `\d{1,3}` only matches one, two or three digits.

Comment: yes i think i forgot to mention it i also need that limitation

Comment: @Darkmagister Ok, I see, you have that in your pattern but not listed as a requirement.